# SOAP service call fails when SOAPMessage.writeTo is not called

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

I am trying to invoke a **SOAP** service but after I built my `SOAPMessage`, if I call the `SOAPMessage.writeTo(out)` the service invocation is done successfully but when I omit it it fails.

I pretty sure that calling `writeTo()` is not a mandatory step before sending the request and I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Here are the details

My Client

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "https://mydomain.com/webservices/gateway/IdMgt/CorporateDirectoryLookupPort";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        // print SOAP Response
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        soapConnection.close();
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {

        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                + "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"
                + "<soapenv:Header>"
                + "<ns1:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand=\"0\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">"
                + "<ns1:UsernameToken>"
                + "<ns1:Username></ns1:Username>"
                + "<ns1:Password></ns1:Password>"
                + "</ns1:UsernameToken>"
                + "</ns1:Security>"
                + "</soapenv:Header>"
                + "<soapenv:Body>"
                + "<GetAccountDetailsRequest2 xmlns=\"http://anotherdomain/schema/tCorporateDirectoryLookupV1\">"
                + "<MessageHeader xmlns=\"\"/><UserID xmlns=\"\"></UserID>"
                + "<AccountID xmlns=\"\">ServiceDeskAPIprd</AccountID>"
                + "</GetAccountDetailsRequest2></soapenv:Body>"
                + "</soapenv:Envelope>";

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(
                null, is);

        /* Print the request message */
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();
        return soapMessage;
    }
}
```

When `soapMessage.writeTo(System.out)` in `createSOAPRequest` is **NOT** commented out I get a valid response but when it is commented out I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
   <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">lxvirt150</ns2:hostname>
   </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I'm running into the very same issue. I noticed that the field "messageByteCount" of the SoapMessage was updated after calling the writeTo method (from 0 to 524 in my case).

I also noticed that the saveMessage method was called during the execution of the writeTo method, so I tried that instead of calling writeTo (right after the call to the MessageFactory), but that did not do it. 

Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

By looking into the implementation of the writeTo method, I found out that they set the "SOAPAction" header at the end of it:

```
if (isCorrectSoapVersion(4)) {
        String[] soapAction = this.headers.getHeader("SOAPAction");

        if ((soapAction == null) || (soapAction.length == 0)) {
            this.headers.setHeader("SOAPAction", "\"\"");
    }
}
```

So if you want to avoid a call to the writeTo method, you can actually set the header yourself right after the creation of the SOAPMessage :

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(
            null, is);
soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("SOAPAction", "\"\"");
```

That worked for me. I hope that helps!

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue but found the saveChanges() method solved it. From the java doc:

```
Updates this SOAPMessage object with all the changes that
have been made to it. This method is called automatically when
SOAPMessage writeTo(OutputStream) is called. However, if
changes are made to a message that was received or to one that has
already been sent, the method saveChanges needs to be
called explicitly in order to save the changes. The method saveChanges also generates any changes that can be read back (for example, a MessageId in profiles that support a message id). All MIME headers in a message that is created for sending purposes are guaranteed to have valid values only after saveChanges has been called.
In addition, this method marks the point at which the data from all
constituent AttachmentPart objects are pulled into the
message.
```